# Turn string into array of objects

Tags: javascript

I would like to spilt the string by '|' and ':' and end up with an object with a key value relationship inside of an array.

It would look like this

```
[{key1 : red, key2 : five},{key1 : blue, key2 : six},{key1 : yellow, key2 : nine}, {key1 : black, key2 :ten}]
```

This is what I have so far

```
var  x = "red:five|blue:six|yellow:nine|black:ten"
     datesArray = [],  
     datesObj = {}, 
     keys = ['key1','key2'],
     dates = x.split('|');

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { 
    datesArray.push(dates[i].split(':'));
}

for(var x = 0; x < datesArray.length; x++){
    datesObj[keys[0]] = datesArray[x][0]
    datesObj[keys[1]] = datesArray[x][1]
}

console.log(datesObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zPS7h/4/

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zPS7h/15/

```
var x = "red:five|blue:six|yellow:nine|black:grey";

var  datesArray = [],
     keys = ['key1','key2'],
     dates = x.split('|');

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    var values = dates[i].split(':');
    var dateObj = { keys[0]: values[0], keys[1]: values[1] };
    datesArray.push(dateObj);
}

console.log(datesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
s = "red:five|blue:six|yellow:nine|black:ten";
groups = s.split("|");
result = {};
for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  t = groups[i].split(":");
  result[i] = { "key1": t[0], "key2": t[1] };
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var  x = "red:five|blue:six|yellow:nine|black:ten"
     datesArray = [],  
     datesObj = {}, 
     keys = ['key1','key2'],
     dates = x.split('|');

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) { 
    datesArray.push(dates[i].split(':'));
}

var arr = [];

for(var x = 0; x < datesArray.length; x++){
    datesObj[keys[0]] = datesArray[x][0]
    datesObj[keys[1]] = datesArray[x][1]
    arr.push(datesObj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ECMA5 you could do something like this using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Javascript

```
var x = 'red:five|blue:six|yellow:nine|black:ten',
    y = x.split('|').map(function (group) {
        var vals = group.split(':');

        return {
            key1: vals.shift(),
            key2: vals.shift()
        };
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
```

Output

```
[{"key1":"red","key2":"five"},{"key1":"blue","key2":"six"},{"key1":"yellow","key2":"nine"},{"key1":"black","key2":"ten"}]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3rE8H/)